# Whats a good DNS service with an API

Tags: domain-name-system, dns-hosting

Does anyone know a good DNS hosting service that has an API and gives you a reasonable amount of domains / zones for the price?

I'm setting up a hosting service & want to script the creation of the DNS entries through a web app.

Right now our DNS is hosted with Slicehost.com where they have an API and unlimited DNS entries included with every account.

I was just wondering if there was anything out there that was DNS only.

Thanks!

Comment: Product recommendations are off topic per the FAQ.

Answer (score 3):

**Amazon [Route 53](http://aws.amazon.com/route53/) comes to mind.**

It's an extremely scalable pure DNS hosting service with 'pay for what you use' pricing, and it's [API managed](http://aws.amazon.com/documentation/route53/).

**Some highlights of Route 53:**

- It uses Anycast'ed DNS server nodes spread out over [18 POPs around the globe](http://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2011/02/08/new-edge-location-paris/).
- They thought about security. I can't find the exact post right now, but from their community forum posts it's clear that Amazon thought about [DDoS attacks](http://blog.easydns.org/2010/08/19/dos-attacks-and-dns-how-to-stay-up-if-your-dns-provider-goes-down/) against their infrastructure etc. during their design phase.
- Route 53's edge locations receive changes quite fast, in [around one minute](http://aws.amazon.com/route53/faqs/#Route_53_change_propagation).
- The [pricing model is clear, and DNS queries are cheap -- only $0.50 per million queries](http://aws.amazon.com/route53/pricing/).
- Backed by Amazon, currently the largest 'cloud computing' player, and [has an SLA](http://aws.amazon.com/route53/sla/).

On the downsides, some use cases don't fit well with the Route 53 pricing model -- especially people who lave lots of 'dormant' domains don't like the [1 USD pr zone-month](http://aws.amazon.com/route53/pricing/) fee.

**Or,** if you're looking for something a little more capable, then **DynDNS' DynECT platform comes to mind**. DynDNS has a long track record for excellent DNS hosting, and is the [DNS host for StackExchange](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/09/new-dns-provider/). Their DynECT is kind of expensive (~200 USD/month), but it has neat things like Global Server Load Balancing / GeoDNS; good GUI, telephone support etc. And from their website copy, it seems [DynECT has an API as well](http://dyn.com/enterprise-dns/dynect-platform) (I haven't used it).

Answer (score 1):

I would highly recommend Zerigo DNS. They have a REST API: http://www.zerigo.com/managed-dns/rest-api

Comment: +1 for Zerigo, we're using them to server over 500k querys a day

Comment: Zerigo has been down for +10hr today due to a DDoS attack. Status updates are slow to come.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.durabledns.com/ -- haven't used the API, but the DNS service is good.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't helpful now/yet, but I have used [DNS Made Easy](http://www.dnsmadeeasy.com/) for a year now and they have been excellent. It looks like they have [future plans](http://www.dnsmadeeasy.com/technology/roadmap.html) to implement an API, but have not done so yet. They only do DNS though, so that answers half of your question :)